# How to avoid duplicate results on elasticsearch/kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have the follow query that returns Exceptions and/or Errors. 
Thing is that it returns same results - which is the exepected behavior from that query.

How could I manage the result that will return only unique results?

this is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "message": "error" }},
        { "match": { "message": "exception" }}
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "message": "io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an aggregation to get (and count) the unique exceptions / errors. Try something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "message": "error" }},
        { "match": { "message": "exception" }}
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "message": "io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "errors_exceptions" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "message" }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: If you do this frequently, it might be cheaper to calculate the hash of the exception upfront, eg [in your logappender (this is just one example, you can probably find something similar for your use case)](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/master/stack-hash.md) or with [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html).